# Include a view not bounded to a specific controller action in Symfony2 with Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'd like to include `form_fields.html.twig` (view not bounded to a controller action) within `edit.html.twig`, actually a view served by `MyController`.

Given the following directory structure:

```
MyBundle
    - Resources
        - views
            - MyController
                - form_fields.html.twig
                - edit.html.twig
```

In my `edit.html.twig` i have:

```
{% block content %}
    <form action="{{ path('packages_edit', { 'slug': slug }) }}" method="post">
        {% include 'form_fields.html.twig' %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Not working, got **template not found exception**. I've tried without success:

- `MyBundle::MyController::form_fields.html.twig`
- `MyBundle::form_fields.html.twig`
- `::form_fields.html.twig`
- `form_fields.html.twig`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
{% include MyBundle:MyController:form_fields.html.twig %}
```